# What makes Eastern Boundary Currents cold?

Tags: atmosphere, oceanography, ocean-currents, coastal

As far as I am aware, there are two separate processes that cause Eastern Boundary Currents (EBCs) to have cold Sea Surface Temperatures (SSTs). One is offshore Ekman transport, which leads to coastal upwelling of cold subsurface waters. The other is simply equatorward advection of cold polar waters. But have there been quantitative studies of which process is dominant?